# Get the return in a function in other function?

Tags: python, function

Is there any way to access to the return in a function inside other function ?

Probably the next code explain more what I want to do.

```
class perro:
    def coqueta(self, num1, num2):
        self.num1 = num1
        self.num2 = num2
        return self.num1 + self.num2

    def otro_perro(self, coqueta):
        print otro_perro




mascota = perro()
ejemplo = mascota.coqueta(5,5)
mascota.otro_perro()

print ejemplo
```

How can i get the return of the first `def` (`coqueta`) to print in the second function (`otro_perro`)?

Comment: Could you plaease clarify your question? What you would like to achieve? There are also a few likely errors in the code: E.g. the reference `otro_perro` (in return) in the method `otro_perro` is not initialized and is not the same as the method call `self.otro_perro` which would lead to an infinite recursion.

Comment: @M.Wymann _how can i get the return of the fist def to the second?_ - that is his question.

Answer (score 2):

Either pass the return value of method `coqueta()` into `otro_perro()`, or have `otro_perro()` call `coqueta()` directly. Your code suggests that you wish to do the first, so write it like this:

```
class Perro:
    def coqueta(self, num1, num2):
        result = big_maths_calculation(num1, num2)
        return result

    def otro_perro(self, coqueta):
        print coqueta

mascota = Perro()
ejemplo = mascota.coqueta(5, 5)
mascota.otro_perro(ejemplo)
```

Or, you could call `coqueta()` from `otro_perro()`:

```
    def otro_perro(self, num1, num2):
        print self.coqueta(num1, num2)
```

but that requires that you also pass values for `num1` and `num2` into `otro_perro()` as well.

Perhaps `num1` and `num2` could be considered attributes of class `Perro`? In that case you could specify them when you create the class:

```
class Perro:
    def __init__(self, num1, num2):
        self.num1 = num1
        self.num2 = num2

    def coqueta(self):
        result = big_maths_calculation(self.num1, self.num2)
        return result

    def otro_perro(self, coqueta):
        print self.coqueta()    # N.B. method call
```

Or another possibility is to cache the result of the "big calculation":

```
class Perro:
    def __init__(self, num1, num2):
        self.num1 = num1
        self.num2 = num2
        self.result = None

    def coqueta(self):
        if self.result is None:
            self.result = big_maths_calculation(self.num1, self.num2)
        return self.result

    def otro_perro(self, coqueta):
        print self.coqueta()    # N.B. method call
```

Now the expensive calculation is performed just once when required and its result is stored for later use without requiring recalculation.

Answer (score 0):

Whats wrong with this?

```
mascota = perro()
ejemplo = mascota.coqueta(5,5)
mascota.otro_perro(ejemplo)
```

or,

```
mascota = perro()
mascota.otro_perro(mascota.coqueta(5,5))
```

Comment: Hello, thank you for your answer, this is just an example I will make a big math calc and I would like to use the result in the second function.

Answer (score 0):

Just make it an attribute of the `perro` class. Thats really the whole point of class, to modularize, organize, and encapsulate your data instead of having to use `global`s everywhere:

```
class perro:
    def coqueta(self, num1, num2):
        self.num1 = num1
        self.num2 = num2
        self._otro_perro = self.num1 + self.num2

    def otro_perro(self):
        print self._otro_perro




mascota = perro()
mascota.coqueta(5,5)
mascota.otro_perro() # will print the value of self._orto_perro
```

I added the extra underscore before `orto_perro` because you had already used that name for your method. And as a unrelated side note, class names a gereral capitalized in Python. So `perro` would become `Perro`.